# I am not being able to install tensorflowjs for nodejs

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, tensorflow.js, node-gyp, gyp

I am trying to install tensorflowjs for node.js using npm. But every time I try to install, I am receiving `npm ERR! node-pre-gyp install failed with error: Error: Command failed: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`

Here is the complete log

```js
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path G:\Projects\NLP\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/install.js
npm ERR! CPU-windows-4.16.0.zip
npm ERR! https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/libtensorflow/libtensorflow-cpu-windows-x86_64-2.9.1.zip       
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp install failed with error: Error: Command failed: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build  
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@1.0.9
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@18.12.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info check checked for "G:\Projects\NLP\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\lib\napi-v8\tfjs_binding.node" (not found)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-builds/pre-built-binary/napi-v8/4.16.0/CPU-windows-4.16.0.zip
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-builds/pre-built-binary/napi-v8/4.16.0/CPU-windows-4.16.0.zip
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for @tensorflow/tfjs-node@4.16.0 and node@18.12.1 (node-v108 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error response status 404 Not Found on https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-builds/pre-built-binary/napi-v8/4.16.0/CPU-windows-4.16.0.zip
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.1.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.12.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info ok
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.1.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.12.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.12.1 found at "C:\Python312\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS using VS2022 (17.8.34330.188) found at:
npm ERR! gyp info find VS "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS run with --verbose for detailed information
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Python312\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'G:\\Projects\\NLP\\node_modules\\@tensorflow\\tfjs-node\\build\\config.gypi',     
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\DjBillje\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\18.12.1\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\DjBillje\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\18.12.1',   
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\\\Users\\\\DjBillje\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\node-gyp\\\\Cache\\\\18.12.1\\\\<(target_arch)\\\\node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=G:\\Projects\\NLP\\node_modules\\@tensorflow\\tfjs-node',       
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'G:\\Projects\\NLP\\node_modules\\@tensorflow\\tfjs-node\\build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! Traceback (most recent call last):
npm ERR!   File "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\gyp_main.py", line 42, in <module>
npm ERR!     import gyp  # noqa: E402
npm ERR!     ^^^^^^^^^^
npm ERR!   File "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
npm ERR!     import gyp.input
npm ERR!   File "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\input.py", line 19, 
in <module>
npm ERR!     from distutils.version import StrictVersion
npm ERR! ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:284:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19045
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=G:\\Projects\\NLP\\node_modules\\@tensorflow\\tfjs-node\\lib\\napi-v8\\tfjs_binding.node" "--module_name=tfjs_binding" "--module_path=G:\\Projects\\NLP\\node_modules\\@tensorflow\\tfjs-node\\lib\\napi-v8" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=8" "--node_napi_label=napi-v8"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd G:\Projects\NLP\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v18.12.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.1.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=G:\Projects\NLP\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\lib\napi-v8\tfjs_binding.node --module_name=tfjs_binding --module_path=G:\Projects\NLP\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\lib\napi-v8 --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=8 
--node_napi_label=napi-v8' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (G:\Projects\NLP\node_modules\@mapbox\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:89:23)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19045
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "G:\\Projects\\NLP\\node_modules\\@mapbox\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd G:\Projects\NLP\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v18.12.1
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.9
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! * Downloading libtensorflow
npm ERR!
npm ERR! * Building TensorFlow Node.js bindings

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\DjBillje\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-01-14T04_58_19_666Z-debug-0.log
```

**Things I tried but didn't work:**

1. I have tried installing Build Tools using `Install Additional Tools for Node.js`.
2. I also tried installing Visual Studio C++ Community
   edition.
3. I tried installing it with  `npm install @tensorflow/tfjs-node --unsafe-perm --allow-root`

*When I try to install the older `v2.8.4` of tensorflow. It gets installed with no errors but when I try to run it, I get build error.*

Comment: This error its seems to be related to node-pre-gyp failing during the installation of tensorflowjs-node.

Please check the [nodejs set-up](https://www.tensorflow.org/js/tutorials/setup#nodejs_setup) to install tensorflowjs for nodejs. And follow the step by step instructions mentioned in the same link.

And Sometimes issues can arise due to corrupted npm cache. You can try clearing the npm cache using the following command:  `npm cache clean --force `

I have tried by using this steps . I can able to install successfully. Let us know if the issue is still persists.